# Is there any way to clear cache in JS level. need to clear browser cache/ session and cookies

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I have a http call to an api, the first call is ok, during using the application there are `https` calls under same domain. even though consequence `https` calls are not happening within webview but all `http` url under the same domain will redirect to `https` in the webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work this out through the React Native built-in module.

You can use `RCTNetworking`

```js
var RCTNetworking = require("RCTNetworking");
RCTNetworking.clearCookies();
```